# Protocol function that can take any type that conforms to protocol

Tags: swift

If I create a protocol...

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var someArray: [String] { get }
    init(someArray: [String])
    func adding(_ other: Self) -> Self
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func adding(_ other: Self) -> Self {
        return Self(someArray: someArray + other.someArray)
    }
}
```

Then I can create a struct that conforms to it...

```
struct Foo: MyProtocol {
    let someArray: [String]
}
```

Now I can create two `Foos` and add them together.

But if I create another struct that also conforms to `MyProtocol`...

```
struct Bar: MyProtocol {
    let someArray: [String]
}
```

Then now I cannot do...

```
let foo = Foo(["Hello", "World"])
let bar = Bar(["Goodbye"])
let fooBar = foo.adding(bar)
```

Because the function requires that the type of `other` is the same as the type that you are running the function on.

Is it possible to not have this restriction? To be able to add any type or struct to any other type of struct as long as they both conform to `MyProtocol`?

**THOUGHTS**

Hmm... maybe I'm thinking of trying to solve this in the wrong way? I guess I could solve this by removing the `Self` requirement from the input parameter of the function and just using `[String]` as the input parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that your problem is the `Self` requirement. But you don't need it, at least not when it comes to the argument. You just want something that conforms to `MyProtocol` so that you can take `someArray` from it and create a new instance of `Self`:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   var someArray: [String] { get }
   init(someArray: [String])
   func adding(_ other: MyProtocol) -> Self
}

extension MyProtocol {
   func adding(_ other: MyProtocol) -> Self {
       return Self(someArray: someArray + other.someArray)
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Somehow that passed me by. I thought the Self requirement was for the whole thing. Thanks :D Hmm... when I try that it says that it can only be used as a generic constraint because it has self requirement? Will have a look later. Thanks :D